# Rewrite node-links in Drupal 8 with anchor-hashtag e.g. /termname#title instead of /termname/title.html

Tags: anchor, drupal-8, scroll-paging

in my Drupal 8 site, i have sections tagged with terms like "Therapies" and "Team", where the single contents (each therapy, each person ...) are nodes with anchors. The nodes (the whole team for example) are displayed on one page. 
In my menu its not a problem to append the anchor-hashtag to exactly scroll to the single therapy or team-member.

But: I also use entity-references to link to the different nodes. Those links are generated inside the system automatically (e.g. therapy/massage.html). I now want to create a rewrite rule that rewrites all node-links to (e.g.) xxx.xxx.com/therapy#massage, where "massage" is the title of the node.

Hint: It is NOT possible to do this with [pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto)! I already tried that.

Thanks in advance and regard,
Fab

Comment: You probably need to hook into the links and them yourself. Take a look here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Menu!menu.api.php/function/hook_link_alter/8.1.x

Comment: Hey Jamie, thanks. But can you give me a hint how that could look like? And where do i have to place that code? I want the node-title to be appended as anchor-hashtag.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's possible with Url::fromUserInput()

Take a look at the following link: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AfromUserInput/8.1.x

Your code will look something like this

```
$url = Url::fromUserInput('#' . $node->getTitle());
```

Where to put this depends on how you create your page.
If it's a standard view (which I'm assuming) you have to hook into the creation of your link and change the URL.

For the above you need to create a module and add the hook into your .module file.

The hook you're going to need is hook_link_alter(), you can find the documentation here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Menu!menu.api.php/function/hook_link_alter/8.1.x

```
/**
 * Implements hook_link_alter().
 */
function module_link_alter(&$variables) {
  /** @var NodeInterface $node */
  $node = $variables['options']['node'];

  if ($node != NULL){
    $variables['url'] = Url::fromUserInput('#' . $node->getTitle());
  }
```

The code above should get you on your way, I'm not entirely sure if it'll work since I haven't tried it yet.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Jamie and thanks again for your answer.
Do i have to put that in a template.php, or where? Sorry im new to Drupal 8 :/
Could u gimme a hint on that? Would be perfect, thanks in advance.

Comment: @FabUlous Updated my answer

Comment: Wow super! i will test that after the launch. Thank you very much!

Since i had to quickly finish that project, i found a workaround: It is possible to add a hash-sign directly inside the URL-Alias field in the node-edit-form. And this URL is also taken for the whole reference-stuff. It's not a perfect solution, since there is an error-proneness by typing the URL wrong, but since i create and edit the content for the customer, its ok. 

I don't get why its not possible to add the hash-sign in pathauto. Would have been SO easy then!

Comment: @FabUlous That's great, be sure to tell me the test results since I'm curious to see if this works :P